# Как добавить элемент в массив внутри поля jsonb? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Есть поле с типом jsonb, внутри хранится объект:

```json
{
    "type1": [ "uuid1", "uuid2" ],
    "type2": [ "uuid3" ]
}
```

В общем случае необходимо что бы при добавлении нового uuid4 в type1 мы получили

```json
{
    "type1": [ "uuid1", "uuid2", "uuid4" ],
    "type2": [ "uuid3" ]
}
```

а при добавлении uuid5 в type3

```json
{
    "type1": [ "uuid1", "uuid2", "uuid4" ],
    "type2": [ "uuid3" ],
    "type3": [ "uuid5" ]
}
```

как по отдельности это сделать вопросов не возникает, проблема именно с написанием универсального адекватного запроса подходящего под оба кейса

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE table1 SET
    foo = jsonb_set(foo, '{type2}', COALESCE(foo->'type2', '[]') || '"uuid5"')
WHERE id = 'bar';
```